# Arduino - Wifly - Responding to the Http call from Android

Tags: android, http, arduino, android-wifi

I have built an Android App and an Arduino - wifly module. Now the Android app is able to send data to arduino via wifly. As of now I have coded a http params to close the http once after waiting for 2 seconds.

```
final int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 2000;
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
```

Could you please guide how to send response from Arduino to the Android app which has established the HHTP connection with Arduino ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the Arduino board to act as a webserver. There are several tutorials online for that purpose, most notably [the one on arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer).

You should expect to do some more work on the Arduino side to get something useful out of it, though.